# SQL: Remove different rows in a group?

Tags: sql, oracle

A bit hard to explain but I need a query to remove rows that have different values for one grouping..?

example table:

```
1) A  1
2) A  1 
3) B  2
4) B  3 
5) C  3
6) C  3
```

Grouping the columns together: A1 A1 B2 B3 C3 C3. I'd like to remove lines 3 and 4 (B2 and B3) from the table. The letters come from one table, joined with another table that holds the numbers.

If that made sense to anyone, any help would be appreciated.

*edit: Query example to get above table:

```
select a.id, b.id from tableA a
join tableB b on a.first_col = b.second_col
```

Comment: What is the query that generates the data?  That is probably the right place to start.

Comment: It's like.. select tableA.id, tableB.id from table A join table B on A.id = c.id (c is some column in table B)

Comment: @Kuro, that's not much help. Add a proper SQL statement to your question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson added a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious why you want duplicate rows.  This returns one id pair, when all the ids are the same:

```
select a.id, max(b.id)
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.first_col = b.second_col
group by a.id
having min(b.id) = max(b.id);
```

You can include `count(*)` if you want the number of rows matching the ids.

Comment: This is perfect and much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Windowed Aggregates, as most DBMSes don't support `COUNT( DISTINCT) OVER` you can switch the logic to:

```
select col1, col2
from 
 (
   select a.id as col1, b.id as col2
      min(b.id) over (partition by a.id) as mincol2
      max(b.id) over (partition by a.id) as maxcol2
   from tableA a
   join tableB b 
     on a.first_col = b.second_col
 ) dt
where mincol2 <> maxcol2
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm getting a syntax error somewhere. *edit: nvm. figured out the syntax..lemme check if it worked

Comment: I can't get this to work.. always says invalid identifier

Comment: @dnoeth . . . Actually, most databases that support window functions *do* support `count(distinct)`.  But `min()` and `max()` is better anyway.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Which DBMS besides Oracle & DB2, defintely not SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Teradata, MySQL 8/MariaDB?

Comment: @Kuro: What invalid indentifier? It's exactly the same logic as Gordon's, just using Windowed Aggregates instead of Aggregates :-)